# Registration issue with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

After working on codecademy.com and udacity.com to get some understanding of web app development, I'm finally attempting to get my own websites up and running and take a crack at writing an app.  I took some advice and started experimenting with App Engine, but hit a major snag pretty quickly.  I assume that I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't find the right documentation.

End goal:

serve andrewhelloapp.appspot.com from helloworld.axiomofcats.com

Where I am right now:

- as per udacity instructions I signed up for app engine with
  drew.matteson@gmail.com
- I verified with SMS and created a hello world app at
  andrewhelloapp.appspot.com
- I want to serve this off of helloworld.axiomofcats.com (I own
  [axiomofcats.com](http://axiomofcats.com))
- Found instructions to do this at this page: 
  http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99448
- I could not figure out how to associate my drew.matteson@gmail.com
  with Google Apps
- I registered for axiomofcats.com with Google Apps
  (drew.matteson@axiomofcats.com), and went through the process of
  verifying my ownership of the website
- I then attempted to get drew.matteson@axiomofcats.com an app engine
  account
- I could not register it due to the one phone # for SMS verification
  limit

My assumptions so far

- To serve an app off a subdomain helloworld.axiomofcats.com that was
  developed with appengine, I believe I need one account with two
  things

  - access to app engine
  - access to google apps

My perceived problem:

- drew.matteson@gmail.com has access to app engine, but can't register
  a domain with google apps
- drew.matteson@axiomofcats.com has the domain that I want to serve
  from, but can't register for app engine unless I use a phone number
  other than my own

This is similar to the unanswered question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805855/google-app-engine-registering-a-new-application

ideas?

Comment: Your Apps admin account doesn't actually have to be an owner of the app to add it. Just add the App Engine app from the Apps end of things ('add services').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to your App Engine Admin pages -> Permissions
2. Invite your other account as Owner (drew.matteson@axiomofcats.com)
3. Check your email and accept invitation
4. Go to Admin -> Add Domain, enter axiomofcats.com
5. Follow further instructions..